# MySQL join on subquery with calculating distance between coordinates

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, distance

I'm not able to figure out this type of query:
This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.*, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url 
FROM 
  (SELECT id, aid, title_en, title_url_en, address, city_id, zip, district_id, province_id, region_id, country_id, mountain_id, stars, picture, valid_from, valid_to FROM accomodation ORDER BY info_date_add DESC) AS accomodation 
LEFT JOIN db_cities 
  ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries 
  ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
WHERE 
  db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country%' 
  AND db_countries.id = '202' 
GROUP BY accomodation.aid 
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() THEN 0 
  WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 END, accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It's working good... What i need to do is to JOIN one more table called skiresort_locations, but problem is i can't use ON because they aren't join by any column. I want to join it by distance calculated from latitude and longitude.

Table skiresort_locations has columns latitude and longitude and table accomodation has also columns latitude and longitude. I want to join table skiresort_locations and show accomodation, where distance is not larger than 50km. I had an idea to make subquery for ON but i don't know if it's possible.

This is select for calculating distance:

```
(((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) 
                * sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180))
                + cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180))
                * cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - accomodation.longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) AS distance
```

I hope somebody understand my hard explanation (sorry for my english) and will help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, i managed to work it correct :)

For somebody, who will need it, this is how my select looks:

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.*, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url 
FROM (SELECT id, aid, title_en, title_url_en, address, city_id, zip, district_id, province_id, region_id, country_id, mountain_id, stars, latitude, longitude, picture, valid_from, valid_to FROM accomodation ORDER BY info_date_add DESC) AS accomodation 
LEFT JOIN db_cities 
  ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries 
  ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
JOIN skiresort_locations 
  ON 
    (((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*pi()/180))))*
    180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
        < '20' 
WHERE 
  db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country_name%' AND 
  accomodation.region_id = '8' 
GROUP BY 
  accomodation.aid 
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN 
    accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND 
    accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() 
      THEN 0 
  WHEN 
    NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND 
    accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' 
      THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 
  END, 
    accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins can be done on arbitrary expressions, not just `field1=field2`-type expressions.

```
JOIN othertable ON distance_function() < 50
```

would be perfectly acceptable. What matters is whether the expression can be evaluated to a true/false state. If it's true, the records being considered will be part of the join. If it's false, the records are excluded. How you get at that true/false doesn't matter, just that you do end up with true/false.